# Want to add two dynamic numbers in Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel, edit

I am a beginner with Laravel and PHP.

I'd like to add two variables together (`LBV + RBV`), so that I display a total value:

```html
<td><span class="lbv"></span></td>
<td><span class="rbv"></span></td>
```

I have tried adding this snippet but no luck yet:

```
collect([$lbv, $rbv])->sum();
```

Comment: simply do $LBV+$RBV then send it to your view

Comment: could you show by doing `dump($lbv); dd($rbv)` and let us know, what it returns

Answer (score 0):

I think we directly add two variable in laravel blade itself like this

```
<td><span class="total">{{$lbv+$rbv}}</span></td>
```

I hope it solves your issue

Comment: I don't think it would work on his case, if `$lbv` and `$rbv` were just a number `collect([$lbv, $rbv])->sum();` should have worked too. Probably, he might have a different data structure.

Comment: May be.......to